# How to write a "Custom Source" on Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I wanna to write a DataSource which is DataStream from Tarantool-java https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java.

can anybody give me a guide on how to write DataSource by User-defined.

this is my code here:

```
package tarantooljava.streaming.flink_connecter;


import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.tarantool.TarantoolConnection16;
import org.tarantool.TarantoolConnection16Impl;
import splunk.test.TestSchema;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;


import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

/**
 * Created by jaryzhen on 16/4/19.
 */
public class FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace<T> extends FlinkTarantoolJavaSpaceBase<T>{

private  ConsumerThread<T> consumerThread;

public FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace(String ip, int port, String user, String pwd) throws IOException {

    FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace(ip,port,user,pwd,11);
}

public List<T> FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace(String ip, int port, String user, String pwd, int a) throws IOException {
    requireNonNull(ip, "topics");
    TarantoolConnection16 con = new TarantoolConnection16Impl(ip, port);
    con.auth(user, pwd);
    final TestSchema schema = con.schema(new TestSchema());
    List select0 = null;
    for (int i=0 ; i <100 ; i=i+2) {
        select0 = con.select(schema.tester.id, schema.tester.primary, Arrays.asList(i), 0, 30, 0);
        //System.out.println("select0:" +i+ select0);
    }
//        System.out.println(a.size());
//        System.out.println(a.get(0));

    con.close();

    return select0;
}

@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    super.open(parameters);


}



@Override
public void run(SourceContext<T> sourceContext) throws Exception {
    consumerThread = new ConsumerThread<>(this, sourceContext);
}

@Override
public void cancel() {
    // set ourselves as not running
    boolean running = false;
    if(true) {

    } else {
        // the consumer thread is not running, so we have to interrupt our own thread


    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    cancel();
    super.close();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Checkpoint and restore
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

private static class ConsumerThread<T> extends Thread {
    private  FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace<T> flinConsumer;
    private  SourceContext<T> sourceContext;
    private boolean running = true;

    public ConsumerThread(FlinkTarantoolJavaSpace<T> flinkConsumer, SourceContext<T> sourceContext) {
        this.sourceContext = sourceContext;
        this.flinkConsumer=flinkConsumer;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


    }

    /**
     * Try to shutdown the thread
     */
    public void shutdown() {
        this.running = false;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I m reading  Flink-Connector-Kafka source code to understand how does Flink work with Kafka.And writed a Class to try get data from tarantool .but a issue happened.

Comment: Could you share your code and state what the problem is?